# ResponseEntityExceptionHandler returns empty body

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I made 3 classes in order to respond custom json error message:

- **ApiExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler**

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ApiExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {ApiException.class})
    protected ResponseEntity<ApiErrorResponse> handleApiException(ApiException ex) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(ex.getResponse().getStatus())
                .body(new ApiErrorResponse(ex.getResponse().getStatus(),
                                           ex.getResponse().getMessage(),
                                           ex.getResponse().getErrors()));
    }
}
```

- **ApiException extends RuntimeException**

```
@Getter
public class ApiException extends RuntimeException {
    private final ApiErrorResponse response;

    public ApiException(HttpStatus status, String message, List<String> errors) {
        this.response = new ApiErrorResponse(status, message, errors);
    }
}
```

- Response DTO class

```
@Getter
public class ApiErrorResponse {
    private final HttpStatus status;
    private final String message;
    private final List<String> errors;
    private final LocalDateTime timestamp;

    public ApiErrorResponse(HttpStatus status, String message, List<String> errors) {
        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;
        this.errors = errors;
        this.timestamp = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    public ApiErrorResponse(HttpStatus status, String message, String error) {
        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;
        this.errors = Collections.singletonList(error);
        this.timestamp = LocalDateTime.now();
    }
}
```

My controller throws an `ApiException`:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/companies")
@CrossOrigin("*")
@Slf4j
public class CompanyController {
    @GetMapping("")
    public ResponseEntity<List<DepartmentRootResponse>>
    companyList(@RequestParam(value = "active", required = false, defaultValue = "true") Boolean active) {
        List<DepartmentRootResponse> companies = companyService.listCompanies(active)
                .stream()
                .map(company -> new DepartmentRootResponse(
                        company.getName(),
                        company.isActive(),
                        company.getCreated()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        if (companies.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ApiException(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT,
                                   "No company",
                                   List.of("Company not found"));
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(companies);
    }
}
```

My exception is caught in `handleApiException` handler and exception messages are passed correctly. However, I got the empty body message.

I don't know why my `ResponseEntity` is disappeared.

Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

My question code works with other response codes.

I found that my response code "204", which means "no content".

Spring swallowed my body message. That's why my body was not sent.